# iOS:NavegationBar not showing in child views

Tags: ios, iphone, uistoryboard

I'm trying to implement slide menu using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) everything is working just fine but in the child views the navigation bar is not showing it all.
[image]

When it first loads and I click item it would show the tableview.

[image]

After I select any of the views in the tableview the navigation bar it will disappear.

[image]

Any of you knows why this is happening? or how can I fix this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: add in this in ViewDidAppear :     self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

Comment: In which controller you have faced this issue ?

Comment: @KKRocks, I add but it didn't make difference. I have updated my original post

Comment: you need to add navigation controller to this controller.

Comment: @KKRocks, the navigation controller is there.

Comment: No there are not exist any navigation controller where "One" label present.